# How to force the service to run in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a web api project. In services.cs class i am asking it to run 2 services and then only it will start the program.

So my web api hits a external link and if that link is down then my service doesnt start because the code is built in that and it keeps re trying till the link is up.

Now i want a mechanism in which even if the external link is down i want the service to start and keep trying to run that class till the link is up but the program should be up an drunning.

Below is the code in my startup.cs file

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
            services.AddControllers(ConfigureControllers)
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null; // use PascalCase
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
                });

            services.AddHostedService<WorkerClassA>();
            services.AddHostedService<WorkerClassB>();
        }
```

code in worker class a:

```
 public WorkerClassA(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory, ILogger<WorkerClassA> logger, CacheRefreshConfig cacheRefreshConfig)
        {
            _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
            _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
            _cacheRefreshConfig = cacheRefreshConfig;
        }

        public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("iLevel Refresh cache background service is stopped.");
            return base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("iLevel Refresh cache background service has started.");
            await RefreshCache();
            await base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(AppSettings.Current.CacheRefreshDelay, stoppingToken);
                await RefreshCache();
            }
        }
  public async Task RefreshCache()
        {
    try
                        {
                            using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
                            var cache = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<CacheService>();
                            await referenceDataService.LoadReferenceDataFromexternallink();
                            _logger.LogInformation("Cache refreshed successfully");
                            return;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            
                            if (isExceptionLogEnabled)
                            {
                                _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to refresh cache");
                                isExceptionLogEnabled = false;
                            }
                            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                        }
}
```

So how do i start the program even if it tries to hit the external link in Worker class A and if it cannot it just keeps re- trying. I want it to start the program and then keep trying to hit the service.

Comment: It would help to see how WorkerClassA is written.

Comment: @ADyson i have added the code in the question

Comment: @Fildor added the full code.

Comment: @Fildor i only want to do this if it goes inside catch block. Else it needs to wait till data is there

Comment: @Fildor Sorry i am not sure how to do this. So when it goes to catch how do i do that. Like what changes should i make in executeasyn?

Comment: @Fildor i cant find your answer anymore

Comment: @Fildor can you help me with code on how to handle the 3rd service